# Cannot receive form data in Spring application sent from another java application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, url-encoding, forms, http-post

I am trying to post an HTML form from a legacy java application to a Spring based java application.But the form field cannot be received there.
can you please help on how to resolve the issue. 
Note: I am posting the form from tomcat 5.5 to the new Spring application in tomcat 6 though Both the containers reside in the same server.
Below i have given the code snippets:

### The form that I am sending from the legacy application:

```
<form id ="user_Spring" method="POST" action="http://new_application_url/app-root/" ENCTYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="login" value='<%=user_Login %>'>
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('user_Spring').submit();"><font color="red"></>New Application</font></a> |
```

### The Spring MVC Controller where I have defined the method to retrieve the form data:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getMethod(@RequestParam String id ,ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request){

         model.addAttribute("login", id);
         return "index";
    }
```

### The error i am getting in firebug:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not sending the id param from the form, so inside your form you're missing something like

```
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value='[SOME VALUE]'>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your reply..Now i have been able to solve the issue. I just had put id (<input type="hidden" name="login" id="login" value='<%=user_Login %>'>)for the parameter i am passing from html.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a form parameter named 'login' but you expect it to be magically bound to a method param named 'id'.

Rename the method parameter to 'login' or qualify it by specifying the HTTP param name:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getMethod(@RequestParam("login") String id ,ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request){

         model.addAttribute("login", id);
         return "index";
    }
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam

Comment: sorry to misguide you.. but actually right after posting this issue i found the mistake and rectified it.. still no luck.. getting the same issue.

Comment: And really thanks a lot for replying.. Now i have been able to solve the issue. I just had put id (<input type="hidden" name="login" id="login" value='<%=user_Login %>'>)for the parameter i am passing from html. Thank you again